# Swift 3 - SwiftKeychainWrapper: KeychainWrapper.standard.set not persistent

Tags: swift3, keychain

I have installed [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper) on my swift 3 project.

I use the following method to save a value on a given key:

```
let saveSuccessful: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set("hello", forKey: "world")
```

When checking the result of the boolean variable, it is false.

And when I try retrieve the value for the key above as follow:

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "world")
```

the result is nil of course.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

No bug detected at all during the process by xCode.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just activated Keychain sharing on the capabilities options of the project targets and it is now working.